# Concurrency optimization job in V8

Tags: javascript, node.js, v8

When concurrency optimization is triggered, a new optimization job will be dispatched to a child-thread to complete.

How does Runtime know that the optimization job has been completed?

I've found that in runtime function `StackGuard`, the optimized code will be set in JSFunction, but I don't know how this function is triggered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When an optimization job is complete, it signals that fact to the main thread. See the call to `isolate_->stack_guard()->RequestInstallCode()` in `optimizing-compile-dispatcher.cc`. The next stack check in a function will then notice that there is a pending request, and enter the StackGuard function you've already found.

Comment: Thanks!! I've found the communication in `StackGuard::RequestInterrupt`.

Comment: I've done a performance experiment and found that, `base::TimeTicks::IsHighResolution()` in `OptimizedCompilationJob::RecordCompilationStats` may cause a longer lantency (100ms) compared to other steps, even the optimization task, and in some cases, the return value will be false, so **What's the purpose of ths function?**

Comment: Metrics measured with low-resolution clocks are useless/misleading, so the purpose of that logic is to avoid that. On my machine it always seems to return quickly even under high system load, but I agree that the implementation looks like it could get slow _in particular_ when the return value will be `false`. What kind of hardware are you test on?

Comment: `CPU: i5-9500T@2.20GHz` (1 physical cpu with 6 cores); `OS: Ubuntu 20.04`. In this case, I will always get `false`, so when I trigger an optimizing task, this function  would bring a big lantency.

Comment: When on a machine with high-resolution, what are these recorded metrics(almost about execution time) used for? Can they help TurboFan to do optimization?

Comment: Thanks for the machine details, that looks less exotic than I expected. Note that the result of that function is cached, so only the first optimization job will have to pay the price. --The metrics don't help Turbofan, they are for humans. You can dump them to `stdout` using various tracing flags, some of them show up in DevTools profiles, etc.

Comment: Thank you very much!!! I also found that using the `--always-opt` flag, even if it is the first optimization job, there will be no overhead, why? (It did execute `base::TimeTicks::IsHighResolution`)

Comment: I don't know (and I don't know why you ever see it being slow, as I can't reproduce that); best guess: something else called `IsHighResolution()` first, and since the result is cached, the second call is very cheap. (Also, note that `--always-opt`, contrary to what you might expect, will generally reduce performance.)

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! And could you please help to answer this question? [OSR related](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70377600/17374248)