# On-Stack-Replacement in V8

Tags: javascript, node.js, v8

OSR optimization will be triggered when a loop is executed enough times. Marking and triggering an optimization task will occur in `JumpLoop` handler. Two questions about OSR in V8:

1. Unlike ordinary function optimization, triggering an OSR optimization job will not in the next turn after marking. It may take a long period of time between marking and triggering a opt-job, why? What's the condition?
2. How to continue to execute the interrupted function in optimized code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re 1. For several reasons, non-OSR optimization is generally preferable (in short, the generated code will be better). Doing OSR is only worth it when the function in question spends a *really* long time in a loop. So the purpose of waiting a bit is to see if the loop will finish soon enough.

Re 2. That's the "magic" of on-stack replacement: the contents of the stack frame are converted to the format that the optimized code for that function needs, and then a special entry point in the optimized code is taken that's able to resume execution from exactly the point where it was interrupted. (That's one of the reasons why non-OSR code is preferable: it doesn't need this special entry point.)

Comment: Is OSR optimization for an entire function or just the loop budy? If it is the latter, what is the difference between the two optimizations? Thank you for your answer! @jmrk

Comment: The optimizing compiler always compiles an entire function (or even more, when it inlines other functions). That said, there are cases where OSR _effectively_ just benefits the loop: AFAIK OSR code has no non-OSR entry point, and if the part after the loop has never been executed yet and hence has not collected any type feedback, its execution will usually be prohibited by a "soft deopt" point: the optimizing compiler can't do much without type feedback, so collecting some and reoptimizing later is usually a good choice.